# Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This is my add to card function

```js
  
  addToCart(product){
    this.storage.get("cart").then((data) =>{
      if (data == null || data.length == 0){
        data = [];
        data.push({
          "product": product,
          "qty": 1,
          "amount": parseFloat(product.price)
        });
      } else {
        let added = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          if( product.id == data[i].product.id )
          {
            console.log("Product is already in the cart");
            let qty = data[i].qty;
            data[i] = qty+1;
            data[i].amount = parseFloat(data[i].amount) + parseFloat(data[i].product.price);
            added = 1 ;
          }
        }
        if (added == 0 ){
          data.push({
            "product": product,
            "qty": 1,
            "amount": parseFloat(product.price)
          });
        }
      }
      this.storage.set("cart", data).then( ()=>{
        console.log("updated");
        console.log(data);

        this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: "Cart Updated",
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      })
    });
  }
```

and when i click to "Add To Card" Button the product it was added successfully. But when i click again its show to me that the product is already added but with an error "Cannot read property 'price' of undefined".
this is the image 
[image]

Comment: You simply removed the item from the cart, so you call `addToCart` with `undefined`. use a console log to see that.

Comment: if you do console.log(data[i].product). are you getting price value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your assigning data[i] to a integer here:

```
data[i] = qty+1;
```

it should be:

```
data[i].qty = qty+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
data[i] = qty+1;
```

It should probably be :

```
data[i].qty = qty + 1;
```

```js
const data = [{
  qty: 1,
  amount: 50,
  product: {
    price: 20,
  },
}];

const i = 0;

let qty = data[i].qty;

console.log('before', data[i]);

console.log('before access', data[i].product.price);

// Problem is here
data[i] = qty + 1;

console.log('after', data[i]);

console.log('after access', data[i].product.price);

data[i].amount = parseFloat(data[i].amount) + parseFloat(data[i].product.price);
```